# SQL Server 2012 identity specification was suddenly reset to not generating primary keys

Tags: sql-server

A primary key column that was set to generate values upon insert with identity specification suddenly stopped doing that - the identity spec was reset to 'No' instead of 'Yes', and identity seed info was lost.

Did this ever happen to anyone?

How can this be reproduced?

A possible workaround is to use self generated primary keys, but I want to keep using the identity spec, and i don't know anymore whether it's reliable or not.

This happened in production, and created a real mess...

Comment: Find out who modified the table or executed the ALTER statement. Schema changes don't happen by themselves. I'd also suggest that you stop using the `sa` account or granting everyone `sysadmin` priviledges.

Comment: I'd also suggest that you *stop* making modifications directly on production and use eg SSDT or Redgate's tools to compare schemas and generate change scripts. You can also use a product like [Redgate's DLM Dashboard](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dlm/dlm-dashboard/) to detect schema changes quickly

Comment: For the moment, you can use previous backups to isolate the time around which the change happened. Maybe that will give you an idea who and what made the change

Comment: Did someone try to change the type of the column from int to bigint? Or try to change the seed? Perhaps they used the wrong statement, disabling IDENTITY instead.

Comment: It was defined as bigint from the beginning.

Comment: And it seems that no one made any changes

Comment: There's a difference between nobody making changes and no one admitting to one that "created a real mess" in production. Does the default trace show any activity that might be correlated?

Comment: @usermax sorry, SQL Server doesn't have ghosts. If you check your backups (assuming you have backups) you'll find the earliest time that someone made this change. Fix your processes, don't allow everyone to modify the production database and ensure you have proper control over the update process. Add auditing tools in the meantime - DLM Dashboard is free

Comment: The default trace shows some traces of intruders - failed login attempts. I disabled the firewall rule that enabled access through tcp... The trace doesn't contain any ALTER statement. Only NO STATS:([UP_STATS].[dbo].[CashLog].[DealInvoiceId]) - what could this mean? Also i do know that exact time of the change - the first error message that i received was 11:21

Comment: We don't use sa account... every app has it's own windows and sql user. I don't know if an intrusion actually took place. Probably it did - since there was a schema change. Any suggestions on how to further investigate this issue?

Comment: @usermax check. the. backups. I don't see any reason to assume that an intruder modified the schema just for laughs. He couldn't - unless the applications run with schema modification privileges. Which means that either you *do* allow people and apps to run as sa or the equivalent.

Comment: @usermax you'll find it very hard to convince anyone that this wasn't a botched update, especially if you *don't* have auditing enabled. Failed login attempts aren't intrusions by definition. It's the *successful* attempts that matter. Wait......

Comment: @usermax *access through TCP ?* You mean the database was open to the entire Internet? Or simply that TCP access is allowed from web servers to the database? Was a VPN used to connect from the outside or not?

Comment: tcp 1433 was open to allow remote access

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134975/discussion-between-usermax-and-panagiotis-kanavos).